# Generics methods overload resolution

Tags: c#, generics

I've read quite a bit about C# generics and method overloads but I can't seem to be able to achieve what I want.
I want to make a method that compares two objects, or two doubles with a given delta (much like Assert.AreEqual) but which could also support Collections of such objects, including Dictionary and SortedList.

Here is my code, but the last generic overload seems to be taking over more specific overloads :/
Could someone tell me how to fix that ?

```
    private bool DeltaEquals<T>(IEnumerable<T> value1, IEnumerable<T> value2, double delta)
    {
        var iter1 = value1.GetEnumerator();
        var iter2 = value2.GetEnumerator();
        for (;;)
        {
            var next1 = iter1.MoveNext();
            var next2 = iter2.MoveNext();
            if (next1 != next2) return false;
            if (!next1) return true;
            if (!DeltaEquals(iter1.Current, iter2.Current, delta)) return false;
        }
    }

    private bool DeltaEquals<T, U>(KeyValuePair<T, U> value1, KeyValuePair<T, U> value2, double delta)
    {
        return DeltaEquals(value1.Key, value2.Key, delta) && DeltaEquals(value1.Value, value2.Value, delta);
    }

    private bool DeltaEquals(double value1, double value2, double delta)
    {
        return Math.Abs(value1 - value2) <= delta;
    }

    private bool DeltaEquals<T>(T value1, T value2, double delta)
    {
        return object.Equals(value1, value2);
    }

    // example of call:
    SortedList<DateTime, double> coll1, coll2;
    ...
    Assert.IsTrue(DeltaEquals(coll1, coll2, 1E-5));
```

Comment: How are you calling them?

Comment: I added an example at the end of my code

Comment: I think you should consider implementing your own `IEqualityComparer` instead, to be honest: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123(v=vs.110).aspx Considering generics are (partly) to help with code re-usability - this is looking quite lengthy.